# Image quality decreases after cropping image

Tags: android, image, image-processing, crop

*I am working on an application in which i have to take image,crop it and then proceed to further implementation.When i capture image and save it to sdcard it's quality is good but when i try to save image after cropping,It's quality is worst.
Below is my code

```
@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     if (arg0.getId() == R.id.captureimage) {
         try {
                //use standard intent to capture an image

                final Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

                startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_CAPTURE);
            }
         catch(Exception e){ String errorMessage = "your device doesn't support capturing images!";
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();}
        }
}
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == CAMERA_CAPTURE) {
        Uri picUri = data.getData();
        performCrop(picUri);
    }
    else if(requestCode == PIC_CROP){this.finish();
    Intent i=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),display.class);
    i.putExtra("jao", "jao");
    startActivity(i);}

    else {
        Log.v("", "User cancelled");
    }
}private void performCrop(Uri picUri) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Intent cropIntent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
    //indicate image type and Uri
cropIntent.setDataAndType(picUri, "image/*");
    //set crop properties
cropIntent.putExtra("crop", "true");
    //indicate aspect of desired crop
cropIntent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
cropIntent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
    //indicate output X and Y
cropIntent.putExtra("outputX", 256);
cropIntent.putExtra("outputY", 256);
 File file = new File(_path);
Uri outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
cropIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);
    //retrieve data on return
cropIntent.putExtra("return-data", true);
    //start the activity - we handle returning in onActivityResult
startActivityForResult(cropIntent, PIC_CROP);
}
```

Please guide me how can i make my cropped image quality better because with bad quality image  i cannot do my other tasks....

Comment: Did you intend to crop it to 256x256 pixels? That's tiny.

Comment: if I change it other than 256X256 cropper does not save any image on sdcard...